# Comparing two set of strings

Tags: java, comparison

Here is my problem. I'm trying to compare two different string by using `&&` and also `.equals` but seems like it cannot give me the result it should be.

Here is my code (starting from where I think is the problem is) :

```
    for(int i = 0; i < datalist.size(); i+=3)   {       

        String temp1 = datalist.get(i);
        String temp2 = datalist.get(i+1);

        System.out.println(temp1);
        System.out.println(temp2);

        if (temp1.equals(dataquery1)) {

            System.out.println("TRUE");

            if (temp2.equals(dataquery2))   {

            System.out.println("TRUE");
            array2.add((datalist.get(i)));
            array2.add((datalist.get(i+1)));
            array2.add((datalist.get(i+2)));

            }   
        }

    }

    System.out.println("\n\nArray2 size : " + array2.size());
    for (int j = 0; j < array2.size(); j++) {

        System.out.println("Array2 : " + array2.get(j));

    }
```

This is the array :

```
[0]  Lipase B
[1]  X-33
[2]  pPICZ?A
[3]  Candida antarctica lipase B (CALB)
[4]  SMD1168H
[5]  pGAP?B
[6]  Lip 2
[7]  X-33
[8]  pPICZ?A
```

And the result is :

```
Lipase B
X-33
Candida antarctica lipase B (CALB)
SMD1168H
Lip 2
X-33


Array2 size : 0
```

The result it should be is :

```
TRUE
TRUE

Array2 size : 3
Array2 : Lipase B
Array2 : X-33
Array2 : pPICZ?A
```

I tried using `if (temp1.equals(dataquery1) && temp2.equals(dataquery2))` but it doesn't work.
However if I change the `dataquery1` and `dataquery2` with its value `Lipase B` and `X-33` respectively, the code works fine.

Can anyone help?

Comment: So what's wrong if it works when you change `dataquery1` and `dataquery2`?

Comment: `dataquery1` and `dataquery2` is retrieved from my SearchData.jsp so that user can query any data they want. If I already change both of it into a string, then there are no use.

Comment: I cannot fully understand what you want...

Comment: @kaixasK Yes, but if none of them match, the output is what it's supposed to be, according to the provided code.

Comment: @kaixasK the list you shown  contains `Lipase B` and you said at the end that if you change `dataquery1` to `Lipase` than equals return true thats kind of contradictory

Comment: @Ricardo I was wondering why is that when I change the `dataquery` to a string like this : `temp1.equals("Lipase B)` and `temp2.equals("X-33)` it gives the correct result, but when it is like this : `temp1.equals(dataquery1)` and `temp2.equals(dataquery2)` it is not.
Both of it should produce the same result, am I right?

@singhakash yes, it supposed to be `Lipase B`. My mistake. Corrected.

Comment: The only reason that I can figure out is the strings being different from "Lipase B" and "X-33". Look for invisible characters in the strings from ```datalist```...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of things, you're setting dataquery1 to "Lipase" when you should be setting it to "Lipase B". If you fix that, I get the correct output:

```
Lipase B
X-33
TRUE
TRUE
Candida antarctica lipase B (CALB)
SMD1168H
Lip 2
X-33


Array2 size : 3
Array2 : Lipase B
Array2 : X-33
Array2 : pPICZ?A
```

Comment: Okay, this is weird. 
I tried this before and it won't work. 

Thank you very much. 

But how about if I only want to put a partial of the query like `lip` and it can gives me all array that contains `lip` in the string?

My lecturer said something about regular expression or `regex` but I'm not sure..

Comment: You can either use a regex or you can use indexof, e.g...

    if (temp1.indexOf(dataquery1) != -1) {
      //code
    }